# MS Access FIlter on subform changing values of other fields

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba

I have a datasheet subform with a combobox name Loan_ID_cbo. Whenever I update the filter via the combobox, the subform is updating the Loan ID (primary key) with the selected Laon ID from the subform, thereby changing the data on the table.

I would like to only filter this data and not allow the filter to edit the data on the table. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my VBA code for the After_Update event:

```
Private Sub Loan_ID_cbo_AfterUpdate()

Application.Echo False

Me.Filter = "MyKey = '" & Loan_ID_cbo & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True

If Loan_ID_cbo = "" Then
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.FilterOn = False
End If

Application.Echo True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your combobox is in the subform datasheet. Thus the combobox appears on each row.

It does happen probably because your combobox is bound to the field Mykey. So changing the combobox do change the value of Mykey.

You should not make a filtering combobox out of the myKey field in the subform, you should make an unbound combobox in the parent form :

1. In the subform, delete this combobox, and add a new textbox and bind it to Mykey.
2. On your mainform, create a new combobox and use this one to filter your subform. So the code would be something like :

   ```
   Private Sub Loan_ID_cbo_AfterUpdate()

       Application.Echo False

       Me.subformname.Form.Filter = "MyKey = '" & Loan_ID_cbo & "'"
       Me.subformname.Form.FilterOn = True

       If Loan_ID_cbo = "" Then
           Me.subformname.Form.Filter = ""
           Me.subformname.Form.FilterOn = False
       End If

       Application.Echo True

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Also, remove `Echo False`. Setting `Me.Painting` to False, then True, will do.

Comment: The combobox was in thetop main form filtering the datasheet. However, I   made the combobox Unbound and it solved the problem. Would this also work to unfilter the datasheet using combobox? Thanks

Comment: if it was on the mainform then it changed the value, and you could not filter anything using `me.filter`, you have to use `me.subformname.form.filter`. And yes your code will unfilter if the combobox is empty